# Dracula theme in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, bash, themes

I am using dracula theme in ubuntu.

I ran program in bashscript but after executing it colorized on next line.

Am I doing any mistake or it is due to theme?
How can I fix it?

Here is code: bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..9}
do
        for j in {1..9}
        do
                total=$(( $i+$j ))
                tmp=$(( $total%2 ))

                if [ $tmp -eq 0 ];
                then 
                        echo -e -n "\033[47m  "
                else
                        echo -e -n "\033[40m  "
                fi
        done
        echo ""
done
echo -e "\n"
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GRD.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "it overlaps"? It colorizes the prompt? You have to reset using `tput sgr0` or something like `printf '\033[0;10m'`.

Comment: Side note: your tests could be simplified to `if (((i + j) % 2))`

Comment: my english is not good thats why I wrote wrong :(

Comment: @Guravsharma: The final `echo` outputs two empty lines. Is this deliberate?

Comment: @Gauravsharma I don't know how your output is related to Count Dracula - it looks to me like a chessboard -, but by at large, it looks reasonable. What is it that you don't like with it?

Comment: @user1934428 After executing this bash.sh file .Every line in terminal is orange colored

Comment: Well, this information should have been put into the question. BTW, as BenjaminW proposed in his comment, using `tput` instead of explicitly hacking in the escape codes, is the better way, because depending on your terminal type, the correct escape codes are generated automatically. But you still keep it a secret, why it is Dracula who was biting you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not connected with Dracula theme.

After all procedures with colors, **you must be reset colors**:

```
echo -e "\e[0m"
```

So, your code must look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..9}
do
    for j in {1..9}
    do
            total=$(( $i+$j ))
            tmp=$(( $total%2 ))

            if [ $tmp -eq 0 ];
            then 
                    echo -e -n "\033[47m  "
            else
                    echo -e -n "\033[40m  "
            fi
    done

echo -e "\e[0m"
```

More about Bash colors you can see [here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

Comment: Oh .Thanks I will see